# type ahead in bootstrap with asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a search box to render data from database using typeahead,I have a webservice that returns values in json format but there is no  data retrieval from database, I can get the values when I directly hit the method but no luck from client side,here is my code

```
<div id="test">
     <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search Code" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $('#test .typeahead').typeahead({
               hint: true,
               highlight: true,
               minLength: 1
           },
           {
               name: 'codename',
               displayKey: 'value',
               source: function (request, response) {
                   $.ajax({
                       url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/service.asmx/codes") %>',
                        data: "{ 'coding': '" + request + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item.split('-')[0],
                                    id: item.split('-')[1]
                                }
                            }))
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

here is my webservice code

```
>  [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public  string[] codes(string coding)
        {
            List<string> _articles = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RetailMS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select Code,Code12 from Detail where " +
                "Code like @coding + '%'";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coding", coding);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            _articles.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["Code"], sdr["Code12"]));
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
                return _articles.ToArray();



            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?